# Android, textviews alignment within listitem

Tags: android, textview, listitem

I want to arrange the text views in each of my list items so that textview (id:lnumber) is on the left end,  textview (id:lname) next to it and the textview (id:lname1) under textview (id:lname)

I was able to align the first two textviews but am unable to arrange the third, right below the second

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Number" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

add some padding to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lname"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RelativeLayout .or use another LinearLayout in the first LinearLayout ,just make textview2 and textview3 in the new LinearLayout .